# Why default packaging info is not present in Maven Super POM?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

Why default packaging info is not present in Maven Super POM? By default it is `jar` if you don't mention it in the POM. But from where the default info is coming? I thought it would be in super POM but could not find there.

Comment: This is define in the xsd schema http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd